# Implementation of a multidimensional array contiguously allocated in memory

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, multidimensional-array, contiguous

I want to have the ability to define a general multidimensional array on heap in c++ and I'd like to assign a contiguous memory to the array for fast accessing the elements, (rather than jagged vector of vectors). Here is my implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<unsigned int> VUI;

class Invalid_MDArray : public exception{
public:
    char* what(){
        return "Array cannot be constructed ";
    }
};

template <class T>
class MArray{
private:
    VUI dsize;
    VUI cumsize;
    T* p;
    unsigned int stot;

public:

    unsigned int size(){ return stot; }
    unsigned int size(unsigned int i) { return dsize[i]; }


    MArray(const VUI& a){


        stot = 1;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i<a.size(); i++){

            if (a[i] == 0) {
                Invalid_MDArray o;
               throw o;
           }

           stot = stot*a[i];

           dsize.push_back(a[i]);
           cumsize.push_back(stot);
        }

        dsize.push_back(stot);

        p = new T[stot];


    }


    ~MArray(){

        delete[] p;
    }


    inline T& operator()(VUI&& a){

       if (a.size() != dsize.size() - 1) {

            out_of_range o("Index is out of bound!");
            throw o;

       }

       unsigned int i = 0;
       while (i<a.size()){
            if (a[i]>dsize[i] - 1) {

                out_of_range o("Index is out of bound!");
               throw o;
           }
           i++;
        }

        unsigned int index = 0;

        //      index=i+imax*j+imax*jmax*k

       i = 0;
       while (i<a.size()){

            if (i == 0) {
                index = a[i];
            }
            else {
                index = index + a[i] * cumsize[i - 1];

            }


           i++;
        }


       return p[index];
    }

};


int main(){


    try{
        MArray<int>  t({ 2, 2, 2 });
        t({ 1, 1, 1 }) = 10;
        cout << t({ 1, 1, 1 }) << endl;

        // I prefer accessing the elements like this -> cout<<t(1,1,1)<<endl;

        MArray<int>  tt({ 2, 0, 2 }); // OOPS! cannot construct this array!
        cout << t.size()<<endl;
        t({ 1, 2, 1 }) = 1000; //OOPS! outofbound exception!
    }
    catch (exception &e){
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

    getchar();
}
```

However, I don't like the interface for accessing the array, for example

```
cout << t({ 1, 1, 1 }) << endl;
```

looks ugly.

Is it possible to implement this differently to have better access to elements in a more natural way, like `cout<<t(1,1,1);`, instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would not reinvent the wheel. A quick Google search revealed [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html), a multidimensional array library which seems to fit all of your design requirements.

I would also ask if this is premature optimization. Do you really *need* more speed here? Vectors are really fast.

Comment: operator() is not a solution since you have to define one for each number of dimensions, and the whole point of multidimensional array is that user may specify custom number of dimensions at runtime.

Comment: @KjMag You are correct. I have removed that from my answer.